# Warning: ZIP extension needs to be loaded for OpenCart to work

Tags: php, server, hosting, whm, opencart2.x

I have got following error during installation step 2 in OpenCart 2.0.3.1.

> Warning: ZIP extension needs to be loaded for OpenCart to work

I think, this is server issue. but, I can not proper judge. How can is solved this. So, Please Guide me step by step for install ZIP PHP extension in server.

Answer (score -2):

I will guide you:

1. Go to Google.com
2. Enter in the box "install ZIP PHP extension in server"
3. Click on one of the top links
4. Do what it says there

If that fails, ask another question that shows you have done your research.